# WebStorm formatting long JavaScript object property value

Tags: javascript, webstorm, code-formatting

If my JavaScript object property value, exceeds my right margin, WebStorm will break it to a second line by concatenating with the `+` sign. This is all fine. I got a problem with the code style formatting here.

Is there any possibility, that WebStorm would add proper indentation for this?

```
var obj = {
  foo: "This is a much too long string " +
    "which should be indented as shown here"
}
```

Instead it strips the indentation from the wrapped line like so:

```
{
  foo: "This is a much too long string " +
  "which should be indented here"
}
```

Is this intended behaviour?
Perhaps I got the settings wrong somewhere?

I am using the default code style settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set option "Align object properties" = "On value". Multiline text will be formatted with the same indent for each text line.
You can find this option at the Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript page - Other tab.